# Google Translate Api for .NET 2.0

Tags: .net, google-api

does anyone know how i can use the Google Translate Api .NET dlls for .NET version 2.0 ?

They are compiled for .NET 3.5 and not .NET 2.0.

Is there any workaround ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

did you try compiling it on .net 2.0 ?
here is the source code : http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/20120504-1.2.4507-beta/Generated/ZipFiles/google-api-dotnet-client-1.2.4507-beta.source.zip

Comment: it does not compile in VS 2005 because the solution is generated in VS 2010.

Comment: isn't there a way to compile the google api in .net 2.0 ??

is .net 3.5 required ??

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it.

I had problems with the SampleHelper dll.

So i compiled it under VS2008 and referenced it in VS2005 and it worked..